# How to translate the following into a tail recursive procedure?

Tags: lisp, scheme, tail-recursion

I have the following mathematical expression:

```
; f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)   where n >= 2 
; f(n) = n where n < 2`
```

Which I translated into a normal recursive LISP call:

```
(define (f n)
  (cond ((< n 2) n)
        (else (+ (f (- n 1))
                 (f (- n 2))))))
```

How would I translate the above into a tail-recursive procedure?  I'm not used to functional programming so I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: [This answer to a question about tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion/36985#36985) appears to be what you want.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sadly, you linked to the wrong answer :*( The correct one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion/33931#33931

Comment: @leppie They're both useful. One is talking about lisp tail recursion, the other is about creating a tail-recursive fib. Put them together and there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about established example of tail recursive transformation for computing Fibonacci numbers. You can find excellent description with code samples at [this chapter](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.2) of SICP.

Comment: That's very funny. I wrote my "mathematical" function to try and solve a SICP problem, but didn't realize I ended up writing the fibonacci function. Thanks a mil, the answer is clear as day in that chapter.

Answer (score 5):

(The following code is written and tested in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org).)

Start with the naive version:

```
;; fib : nat -> nat
(define (fib n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [(= n 1) 1]
        [else (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))]))
```

As we develop new versions, we can use `test` to see if they agree with the initial `fib` (at least on the numbers 0 through 9).

```
;; test : (nat -> nat) -> boolean
;; Check that the given function agrees with fib on 0 through 9
(define (test f)
  (for/and ([i (in-range 10)])
    (= (f i) (fib i))))
```

First, the crucial observation that enables everything else is that when we compute `(fib N)`, we have computed `(fib (- N 1))`... but we discard it, and so we have to recompute it again later. That's why naive `fib` is exponential-time! We can do better by keeping it around, say with an auxiliary function that returns a list:

```
;; fib2list : nat -> (list nat nat)
;; (fib2list N) = (list (fib (- N 1)) (fib N))
(define (fib2list n)
  (cond [(= n 1) (list 0 1)]
        [else (let ([resultN-1 (fib2list (- n 1))])
                (let ([fibN-2 (first resultN-1)]
                      [fibN-1 (second resultN-1)])
                  (list fibN-1
                        (+ fibN-2 fibN-1))))]))

;; fib2 : nat -> nat
(define (fib2 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (second (fib2list n))]))

(test fib2) ;; => #t
```

The `fib2list` function stops at 1, so `fib2` handles 0 as a special (but uninteresting) case.

We can rewrite this in continuation-passing style (CPS) to make it tail recursive:

```
;; fib3k : nat ((list nat nat) -> nat) -> nat
(define (fib3k n k)
  (cond [(= n 1) (k (list 0 1))]
        [else (fib3k (- n 1)
                     (lambda (resultN-1)
                       (let ([fibN-2 (first resultN-1)]
                             [fibN-1 (second resultN-1)])
                         (k (list fibN-1
                                  (+ fibN-2 fibN-1))))))]))

;; fib3 : nat -> nat
(define (fib3 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (fib3k n (lambda (resultN)
                         (let ([fibN-1 (first resultN)]
                               [fibN (second resultN)])
                           fibN)))]))

(test fib3) ;; => #t
```

Now instead of making a non-tail recursive call, `fib3k` calls itself with an extended continuation that takes a list result. The continuation `k` of `(fib3k N k)` is called with a list equivalent to `(list (fib (- N 1)) (fib N))`. (Thus if the first argument is `(- n 1)`, the continuation argument is named `resultN-1`, etc.)

To start everything off, we provide an initial continuation that takes the result `resultN`; the second element is equal to `(fib N)`, so we return that.

Of course, there's no reason to keep packaging things up as a list; we can just make the continuation take two arguments:

```
;; fib4k : nat (nat nat -> nat) -> nat
(define (fib4k n k)
  (cond [(= n 1) (k 0 1)]
        [else (fib4k (- n 1)
                     (lambda (fibN-2 fibN-1)
                       (k fibN-1
                          (+ fibN-2 fibN-1))))]))

;; fib4 : nat -> nat
(define (fib4 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (fib4k n (lambda (fibN-1 fibN) fibN))]))

(test fib4) ;; => #t
```

Notice that there are only two *variants* of continuation in the program---they correspond to the two occurrences of `lambda` in the code. There's the initial continuation, and there's a single way of extending an existing continuation. Using this observation, we can transform the *continuation functions* into a *context data structure*:

```
;; A context5 is either
;;   - (initial-context)
;;   - (extend-context context5)
(struct initial-context ())
(struct extend-context (inner))
```

Now we replace the expressions that created *continuation functions* (ie, the `lambda`s) with uses of the *context constructors*, and we replace the (single) site that applied a continuation function with a new explicit `apply-context5` function that does the work previously done by the two `lambda` expressions:

```
;; fib5ctx : nat context5 -> nat
(define (fib5ctx n ctx)
  (cond [(= n 1) (apply-context5 ctx 0 1)]
        [else (fib5ctx (- n 1)
                       (extend-context ctx))]))

;; apply-context5 : context5 nat nat -> nat
(define (apply-context5 ctx a b)
  (match ctx
    [(initial-context)
     b]
    [(extend-context inner-ctx)
     (apply-context5 inner-ctx b (+ a b))]))

;; fib5 : nat -> nat
(define (fib5 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (fib5ctx n (initial-context))]))

(test fib5) ;; => #t
```

(When compilers do this, they call it defunctionalization or closure conversion, and they do it to turn indirect jumps into direct jumps.)

At this point, it's really obvious that the `context` data type is totally boring. In fact, it's algebraically equivalent to the natural numbers! (A natural number is either zero or the successor of a natural number.) So let's just change the context data type to use natural numbers rather than some heap-allocated structure.

```
;; A context6 is just a natural number.

;; fib6ctx : nat context6 -> nat
(define (fib6ctx n ctx)
  (cond [(= n 1) (apply-context6 ctx 0 1)]
        [else (fib6ctx (- n 1)
                       (+ ctx 1))]))

;; apply-context6 : context6 nat nat -> nat
(define (apply-context6 ctx a b)
  (cond [(= ctx 0)
         b]
        [else
         (apply-context6 (- ctx 1) b (+ a b))]))

;; fib6 : nat -> nat
(define (fib6 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (fib6ctx n 0)]))

(test fib6) ;; => #t
```

But now it's obvious that `fib6ctx` just counts `ctx` up as it counts `n` down to 1. In particular:

```
(fib6ctx N M) = (fib6ctx 1 (+ N M -1))
              = (apply-context6 (+ N M -1) 0 1)
```

and so

```
(fib6ctx N 0) = (apply-context6 (+ N -1) 0 1)
```

So we can get rid of `fib6ctx` entirely.

```
;; apply-context7 : nat nat nat -> nat
(define (apply-context7 ctx a b)
  (cond [(= ctx 0)
         b]
        [else
         (apply-context7 (- ctx 1) b (+ a b))]))

;; fib7 : nat -> nat
(define (fib7 n)
  (cond [(= n 0) 0]
        [else (apply-context7 (- n 1) 0 1)]))

(test fib7) ;; => #t
```

And that's the traditional iterative version of Fibonacci, except that `apply-context7` is usually called `fib-iter` or something like that, and most versions count up instead of down and hope they get the comparison right so they don't get an off-by-one error.